# ScrollToAsync doesn't work in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, button

This `code` works flawlessly on `iOS`, but when I press this button on `Android` nothing happens.

```
btn.Clicked += async (s, e) =>
            {
                await scrollPage.ScrollToAsync(0, 150, true);
            };
```

Screenshots

On Android

[image]

**On iOS**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have had problem with the ScroolTo on android for ages... 
But i have found that if you have some kind of xamarin element to get the position of, it works for me on Android.

Ex:

```
await scrollPage.ScrollToAsync(0, scrollPage.GetScrollPositionForElement(<elementLikeAButton>, ScrollToPosition.Center).Y, true);
```

Comment: Your example works on iOS like a charm, but the problem still presents on Android.

Comment: That is really weird, is this when you open the keybord?
*edit* and is the element you are trying to scroll to at the buttom or top of the page?